# will hibernate's Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW solve database table locking issues?

Tags: spring

currently we are using @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) for a org.springframework.stereotype.Service class, we find that there are many table locks recently coming from this service.

will changing to @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) solve this locking issue? thank you.

Comment: this service is autowired (via @Autowired) into a org.springframework.stereotype.Controller class and is being called from this controller class, oh, i will change to spring question. thank you.

Comment: Deadlocks (assuming that's what *locks* means) occur due to isolation level, not propagation mode. The later simply says whether or not a transaction is required for an operation, and if yes, whether the operation requires its own separate transaction, can join a running transaction, or should be executed as a sub-transaction. Check the isolation level in use for your database or the default isolation level in use for the application. A restrictive isolation level such as `SERIALIZABLE` is likely to cause many deadlocks. Review if you really require such restrictions for every operation.

Answer (score 0):

In any case what I would do is to try to update your records in single spring transaction and I'd not use REQUIRES_NEW in DAO layer but in service layer.